# How to nest other telerik controls listview, chart, inside Telerik LiveTile control and databind them

Tags: c#, web-services, listview, telerik, live-tile

The topic says it all essentially.  I need to have my live tiles display various types of data, such as lists, charts, etc, and have them auto update by pulling data from web service.  I need to know how can I host listview or a chart control inside live tile control.
My current setup is a Telerik RadTileList that I add dynamically to in code behind my custom class that inherits from Telerik LiveTile, I specify my webservice that for example can get back a list object with a couple of fields.
I know I can display them directly in my LiveTile's ClientTemplate referencing them with #= data.FieldName #, but I want the data to be displayed by an imbeded Telerik ListView control that I can hopefully can insert somehow inside my livetile and have the results of the webservice bind to it.

If I'm over-thinking it, or if the architecture can be improved to achieve the same I am open for suggestions as well as long as I can achieve the end result described above.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this. Live tiles only take HTML: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/tilelist-server-side-tile-object.html. Here is what it says for the ClientTemplate: *Gets/sets the **HTML** template that will be instantiated in the tile after live data request.*.

I think that you could get the data, bind it to a hidden listview or chart and move the bound listview/chart in the DOM to inside the tile, via the events and API it has:

- http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/tilelist-tiles-client-side-events-livetile-onclienttemplatedatabound.html
- http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/tilelist-client-side-tile-api.html

but I am not sure if any other functionality of the controls you move will work after that, since you will only be moving their HTML.

You can generate lists with JavaScript if that will work for you and use set_html()...

Comment: Can you expand a bit on how I would go about it given that I'd be getting the data back (and no necessarily in a form of datatables or datasets), but maybe objects such as lists or arrays returned by Webservice.  The trick is that the webservice is being called by the LiveTile and so the object/data coming back to it, so I'm not 100% sure how to connect the 2. Where you suggested adding hidden/separate listview and getting data into it, and then somehow on client side binding it to livetile.  Any pointer to an example if such exists would be highly appreciated.

Comment: So, again, my LiveTile Refreshes every n minutes, calling webservice, gets back a list object with 2 fields for example
I want a ListView control of some sort to display these fields each time as they refreshed.  
The LiveTile is currently added in code-behind using custom class that inherits from LIveTile, this is done so I can add more custom methods/properties to this particular tile type and then easily keep adding this object type to my TileList on the screen and use its drag-drop functions.

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure if there are any examples of that ready, perhaps you will be the one to create the first.
If you get a JSON array by the service perhaps you can bind the listviwe to that (I have not used its client-side binding). THe listview can be in a hidden div right next to the tile for easy access.

Also, consider a ContentTemplate tile where you can place the listview and a few lines of JS with setInterval() to rebind it every n minutes, this may be easier.